# convert docx with (ordered) list to html

Tags: html, docx

I'm trying to convert a large docx document with several layers' ordered list to an html. (see an example of the document here: http://docdro.id/X1oyfBv You should download it)

I tried the following things, including:

- online converters such as html-cleaner and index.html (which only recognize one layer of the list)
- save as html - which creates an horrendous file but still doesn't recognize the ol structure.
- saved the file as zip and then opened the xml file, but I dont see an easy way to get the ol structure out of the w:... tags
- saving it to google docs and running Omar Alzabir's script 
  http://omaralzabir.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/GoogleDocsEmail.jpg

btw. If I create a word file with an ordered list with multiple layers and i convert it, it does recognize it as ol's. But the existing file is not recognized as ol's even if I 'un-list' and list it again. So possibly there is something wrong with how the original document was created (?)

Any suggestions much appreciated:) Or indications as to why this problem occurs

Comment: Save it as .docx and see if it works

Comment: @Dipak thats what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandoc` : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc

This is an open source universal command line tool to convert markup source based document files.

You can use it as something like that:

```
  pandoc -o output.html input.docx
```

Comment: thanks! actually for the example document that created it works and ol tags are created. for the actual large document the ol tags are not recognized and instead p tags with numbers 1.2 etc hardcoded are created. I can see if I can create a better example doc for the latter case

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to save a Word-doc in HTML format, with multi-level ordered-lists?

Word-HTML has bugs in its multi-level ordered lists.  For the list-items, the indentation tends to be incorrect and inconsistent.  There's an example [here](https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/users-guide.html#_Toc78446249).

Word-HTML has similar bugs in its multi-level unordered lists.  An example is [here](https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/users-guide.html#_Toc78446248).

I recently wrote a Python program that fixes these bugs, in Word's HTML.  The program is part of [WordWebNav (WWN)](https://jimyuill.com/software/www/WordWebNav/), which is free and open-source.

WWN is an app that converts a Microsoft-Word document to a usable web-page.  It adds some missing features in the Word-HTML web-page (e.g., a navigation pane), and it fixes bugs in the Word-HTML.